# InvalidRequesMessage error when trying Azure AD IDP initiated SSO - Keycloak

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, keycloak, idp

I am using `Keycloak 12.0.1` as an [identity broker](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_identity_broker) and Azure AD as an identity provider using `SAML2.0`. I get below error when trying to do IDP initiated SSO -

[image]

SP initiated sign-on works fine. The error message is not descriptive enough to find the root cause. I've not setup any client in Keycloak, I want this to work just like SP initiated sign-on in which after successful login, Keycloak profile page is displayed.

Below are links to the metadata -

1. [Service Provider Metadata](https://github.com/akashsolanki/samlsso-keycloak-azuread/blob/master/Service-provider-metadata.xml)
2. [SAML Response by Azure AD](https://github.com/akashsolanki/samlsso-keycloak-azuread/blob/master/saml-response.xml)

**Update**:

I forgot to mention that `Keycloak` expects relay-state in IDP initiated sso response (without which Keycloak shows `NullPointerException` on the server console) but I'm not sure what value I should provide for relay-state here because I've not setup any custom clients. I want Azure AD to redirect to the default client that Keycloak provides (i.e account-console).

I grabbed relay-state from SP initiated sign-on and used the same value for IDP initiated one and the `NullPointerException` goes away but I get 'InvalidRequesMessage'. So I'm suspecting it has to do with the relay-state value I'm using.

Comment: Are you using SAML protocol for brokering with Azure AD? How SAML request to Azure AD looks like? What is in the Azure AD logs?

Comment: Yes, we are using SAML where Keycloak is a broker and Azure AD is an identity provider. I've added the SAML response which Azure AD is sending to the Keycloak. The error happens on Keycloak end, let me see if I can get Azure logs.

Comment: hi @Akash, were you able resolve the issue? I am trying to work around a similar requirement and bumped into the exact same issue. Thanks in advance.